# Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

i am facing this issue "Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileReleaseKotlin'.
"
/Users/alexshami/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color build apk

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/Users/alexshami/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.media2/media2-session/1.2.0/e110e7db678fbfc107af48fe6110e3cc713f4564/media2-session-1.2.0.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
^
../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-4.4.10/lib/src/utils/common.dart:199:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onCreated?.call());
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-4.4.10/lib/src/utils/after_layout.dart:11:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-4.4.10/lib/src/widgets/OverlayCustomWidget.dart:59:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showOverlay());
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-4.4.10/lib/src/widgets/OverlayCustomWidget.dart:66:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-4.4.10/lib/src/widgets/OverlayCustomWidget.dart:73:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!
  ^
  lib/helper/get_color_based_on_theme.dart:11:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  ? SchedulerBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness ==
  ^
  lib/helper/get_color_based_on_theme.dart:22:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  ? SchedulerBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness ==
  ^
  lib/views/screens/tabs/myCart_tab/checkout/checkout_screen.dart:72:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  lib/views/screens/tabs/myCart_tab/checkout/checkout_screen.dart:79:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  lib/views/screens/tabs/myCart_tab/checkout/checkout_screen.dart:85:40: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  final bottomInset = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets.bottom;
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_webview-0.6.2+2/lib/src/web_view/io.dart:25:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(_issue37!);
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_webview-0.6.2+2/lib/src/web_view/io.dart:77:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(_issue37!);
  ^
  ../../../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1/lib/src/widgets/sucessful_widget.dart:57:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _startCountdown());
  ^
  Note: /Users/alexshami/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info-2.0.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/deviceinfo/DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  Note: /Users/alexshami/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-3.5.7/android/src/main/java/app/meedu/flutter_facebook_auth/FacebookAuth.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  e: /Users/alexshami/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1/android/src/main/kotlin/co/paystack/flutterpaystack/FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (48, 62): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
  e: /Users/alexshami/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1/android/src/main/kotlin/co/paystack/flutterpaystack/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (19, 37): Type mismatch: inferred type is BinaryMessenger? but BinaryMessenger was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> BUILD FAILED in 3m 56s

Answer (score 0):

The `overlayCustomWidget` seems to be old. You can either upgrade it or form it to your repo and add it to your project by upgrading the version to support flutter 3+